# Prove that integral is bounded between zero and a series $ \int_1^e [ln(x)]^n \le \frac{e}{n+1} $

Tags: integration, analysis

Really struggling with following:

$I_n =\int_1^e [ln(x)]^n, $ prove that $  0\le I_n \le \frac{e}{n+1}$

It is true for $I_0$ it is also true for $I_1$, but I am stuck with this:

$I_{n+1}\le  \frac{e}{n+2}$

$0 \le (n+2) \int_1^e [ln(x)]^nln(x)dx \le e $

I also tried to compare the deacreasing speed of both $\frac{e}{n+1}$ and $I_n$ but same problem, I don't know what to do with these $ln$ into power:

$I_{n+1}- I_{n} =\int_1^e [ln(x)]^{n+1}dx - \int_1^e [ln(x)]^{n}dx $

Any suggestion would be wholeheartedly welcomed

EDIT: for information, $I_0=e-1$, and $I_1=1 $

Answer (score 2):

Through the substitution $x=e^t$ we have
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1} t^n e^{t}\,dt $$
and since $e^t$ is non-negative and increasing on $[0,1]$, $I_n$ is bounded between $0$ and $e\int_{0}^{1}t^n\,dt = \frac{e}{n+1}$. A more accurate approximation can be deduced from the (convexity) inequalities $e^t\geq(1+t)$ and $e^{t}\leq et-t+1$:

> $$ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}\leq I_n \leq \frac{e+1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}.$$

Additionally, by integration by parts $\lim_{n\to +\infty}n I_n = e.$
And since $I_n$ is a [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)), $\{I_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a log-convex sequence due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Oh.. you are right. Thank you so much. How the variable substitution x=Exp(t) was supposed to come in my mind? Any hints I should be looking when doing this kind of exercise?

Comment: @DenisGantsev: that should be one of the first things to try when dealing with a $\log$!

Comment: I didn't practice enough then :/